# rails custom controller with nested resources: routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes, controller

I have a User controller and related views for index,update, etc. The project specifications changed, and now we have a custom Dashboard controller and related index page, accessed by localhost:3000/dashboard

```
match 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index', as: 'dashboard'
```

The Dashboard index page will act similar to the (old) User index page, and so I am thinking I can simply re-use the User controller actions.
How can I simply "nest" the User into Dashboard, to achieve routes like `localhost:3000/dashboard/users/new` or `localhost:3000/dashboard/users/1/edit`? 
Note that the Dashboard controller does not have an associated model, it is a custom one just to create a customized homepage depending on the person viewing the Rails app. It will have other functionality unrelated to Users.

I tried

```
match 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index', as: 'dashboard' do
  resources :users do

    member do
     #more custom actions
    end

    collection do
     #more custom actions
    end

 end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A namespace should do it:

```
namespace :dashboard do
    root to: "dashboard#index"

    resources :users do
    end
end
```

The route for the dashboard index should be `dashboard_root_path`.

```
app
    controllers
         dashboard
             dashboard_controller.rb
             users_controller.rb
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion, and re-arranged the location of the controllers and view (views/dashboard/user/*). The issue is that rails  is complaining that users_path is undefined for  #<#<Class:0x0000012afccdf0>:0x0000012af97cb8>. This happens when I try to  use the form to create a new user. The offending line is <%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>

Comment: `views/dashboard/user/*` probably a typo, but `user` should be plural. You need to change your form to `simple_form_for([:dashboard, @user])`.